# How minor garbage collection skips older generations?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Minor garbage collection is claimed to be very effective as it does not scan older generations.

How does minor garbage collection detect that there are no references to the young object from tenured or permanent storages without scanning those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Understanding GC pauses in JVM, HotSpot's minor GC](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html), this article will give you pretty detailed explanation of young GC mechanics and write barrier in HotSpot JVM.

In short, old generation is not skipped. All references from old to new are considered as roots for young space GC (same way all reference from new to old are considered roots for old space GC). Trick is that write barrier allows to scan only very small part of old space to find all references to young space.

Comment: Very nice blog about garbage collection pauses. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. While executing, small pieces of code running on reference assignment (called write barriers) record such old-to-young references (either specific objects, or small subregions of the heap to save space). A minor GC *does* looks at those (rare) old objects, it just skips those which are known to not contain young references

Comment: Why not mark younger objects (as referenced from older generations) instead and avoid scanning older ones? Could you recommend further reading?

Comment: @Basilevs Sure, you can do that. It's not usually done though, because it has significant downsides. If the reference is overwritten later, the young object would be promote anyway and stick around until the next major GC. And it interacts poorly with the generational hypothesis, as you now need to scan the whole nursery to promote objects - generational GCs are most effective if most of the nursery is dead, so this would waste time. And in addition, the savings aren't as large as you might imagine.